# Are all Semi-simple commutative Banach algebras finite-dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

I have the following two theorems from functional analysis:

> 1. All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent.
> 2. All norms on a semi-simple commutative Banach algebra are equivalent.

I was then given the following question: does this mean that all semi-simple commutative Banach algebras are finite-dimensional?

My instinct tells me *NO*, but I need to find a counterexample.

Can anybody please give me an example of a semi-simple commutative Banach algebra which is not finite-dimensional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $C(K)$, the continuous functions on an infinite compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you perhaps have a good reference for me to a proof that $C(K)$ is, in fact, semisimple?

Comment: @DJS Note that the maximal ideals are generated by elements $K$, that is to each $x\in K$, the collection $\{f\in C(K):f(x)=0\}$ is a maximal ideal.  Furthermore, every maximal ideal is of this form.  Once you see this, the answer should be clear.

Comment: @Aweygan . Thank you! :). That did make it perfectly clear :D .